# Avoid people from entering my site using anonymous proxy

Tags: proxy, block, anonymous

Avoid people from entering my site using anonymous proxy. Is this possible? I have a wannabe hacker trying to enter my joomla site. My joomla site has a plugin that warns me by email every login attempt and shows me the ip of the computer trying enter. The ip is different every 5 or so attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Check this similar topic from joomla forum http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=267&t=295854

In short what it suggests is

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) || ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']=='') || ($_SERVER['HTTP_VIA']!='')){
        die(" ");
```

This code to be put in *index.php* under joomla root, right after the line `define( '_VALID_MOS', 1 );`

---

You could see some more information on the topic in the article
http://www.wikihow.com/Block-Proxy-Servers

In the last one, there is suggested the following .htaccess rule

```
RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{HTTP:VIA}  !^$ [OR] RewriteCond %{HTTP:FORWARDED}  !^$ [OR] RewriteCond %{HTTP:USERAGENT_VIA}  !^$ [OR] RewriteCond %{HTTP:X_FORWARDED_FOR}  !^$ [OR] RewriteCond %{HTTP:PROXY_CONNECTION}  !^$ [OR] RewriteCond %{HTTP:XPROXY_CONNECTION}  !^$ [OR] RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_PC_REMOTE_ADDR} !^$ [OR] RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTP_CLIENT_IP}  !^$ RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
```

which basically adds several more headers to look for compared to the first approach that was suggested in the joomla forum topic.